# What should I put in the top level of a class definition?

Tags: python

I'm not sure about what should I put in the top level of a class definition.

Here's the code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    print("Here's the top level code in this class")

    def __new__(cls):
        print("Code in __new__ function")
        return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print("Code in __init__ function")
        return
```

What code should I put in the top level? Is there anything that I cannot put in `__new__` and `__init__`? What's the best practice of dividing these code?

Comment: based on the print function style it looks like you're using Python3, if that's the case, you don't need to explicitly subclass `object`

Comment: @RyanHaining That's just my personal preference to write code to be compatible in both 2.7 and 3.3 :-)

Answer (score 0):

class level variables, that is, variables shared by all instances of the class go at the top level

```
class MyClass(object):
    instance_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.instance_count += 1

    def __del__(self):
        MyClass.instance_count -= 1
```

for example.

```
>>> MyClass.instance_count
0
>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> MyClass.instance_count
1
>>> del mc
>>> MyClass.instance_count
0
```

Comment: They could technically be put into `__new__()` though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams a good point, but OP does ask about best practice and that's not really that common

Comment: **Warning**: The example in this answer is academic. `__del__` is not really a destructor and there is no guarantee that this function will ever be called.

Comment: @Matthias the __del__ method is called when the object is about to be destroyed, it may not be called, but that is only assuming the object doesn't go through the destruction steps, which is fine.  This will accurately keep track of the number of live instances regardless of whether or not there is an existing reference to them.